# Git merge --squash did not merge all changes

Tags: git

I had a situation in git when I did `git merge --squash` from one branch to an other but git did not apply all the changes.
Branch `A` is what I merged to `B` and ran `git diff` between those two branches showed me that they are equal.
If I traced one specific change what needed to be removed with merge it was not changed. Can anyone tell me what happened and how to avoid that happening again?

Comment: serverfault.com - servers with faults, faulty servers, serverfault - this will be moved to our sister site stackexchange.com where it's appropriate

Comment: You need to provide much more details for this being something other people can help answering.

Comment: Im sorry, how? What i need to provide?